# Working with data types parameterized by a functor

Tags: haskell, functor, higher-kinded-types

I recently defined a type whose fields I might fail to compute:

```
data Foo = Foo {x, y :: Int, others :: NonEmpty Int}

data Input

computeX, computeY :: Input -> Maybe Int
computeOthers :: Input -> Maybe (NonEmpty Int)
```

Now, one obvious thing I might do would be to just use `liftA3`:

```
foo :: Input -> Maybe Foo
foo i = liftA3 Foo (computeX i) (computeY i) (computeOthers i)
```

That works fine, but I thought it might be interesting to generalize `Foo` to hold `Maybe`s as well, and then transform one type of `Foo` to another. In some similar cases, I could give the `Foo` type a type parameter and derive Traversable. Then after creating a `Foo (Maybe Int)`, I could invert the whole thing at once with `sequenceA :: Foo (Maybe Int) -> Maybe (Foo Int)`. But this doesn't work here, because my function doesn't give me a `NonEmpty (Maybe Int)`, it gives me a `Maybe (NonEmpty Int)`.

So I thought I'd try parameterizing by a functor instead:

```
data Foo f = Foo {x, y :: f Int, others :: f (NonEmpty Int)}
```

But then the question is, how do I turn a `Foo Maybe` into a `Maybe (Foo Identity)`? Obviously I can write that function by hand: it's isomorphic to the `liftA3` stuff above. But is there some parallel of Traversable for this higher-order type, so that I can apply a more general function to this problem rather than re-doing it with a bespoke function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such data types are called "Higher-Kinded Data" (HKD). Manipulating them is often done with Generics or Template Haskell.

There are libraries like [`higgledy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/higgledy) which provide built-in functionality for HKD. I believe [`construct`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/higgledy-0.4.1.1/docs/Data-Generic-HKD-Construction.html#v:construct) is the function you are looking for:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Generic.HKD
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Monoid

data Foo = Foo { x, y :: Int, z :: [Int] }
  deriving (Generic, Show)

emptyFoo :: HKD Foo Last
emptyFoo = mempty

sampleFoo :: HKD Foo Last
sampleFoo = deconstruct (Foo 1 2 [3])

emptyFoo' :: Last Foo
emptyFoo' = construct emptyFoo

sampleFoo' :: Last Foo
sampleFoo' = construct sampleFoo

main = do
  print emptyFoo'
  print sampleFoo'
```

This will print:

```
Last {getLast = Nothing}
Last {getLast = Just (Foo {x = 1, y = 2, z = [3])}
```

---

Edit: I just found out that a much more popular library is [`barbies`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/barbies) (higgledy also depends on barbies). The function that you are looking for is also present in that library as an application of [`btraverse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/barbies-2.0.3.0/docs/Data-Functor-Barbie.html#v:btraverse):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.List.NonEmpty
import Barbies
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Functor.Identity

data Foo f = Foo {x, y :: f Int, others :: f (NonEmpty Int)}
  deriving (Generic, FunctorB, TraversableB, ConstraintsB)

deriving instance AllBF Show f Foo => Show (Foo f)

f :: Applicative f => Foo f -> f (Foo Identity)
f = btraverse (fmap Identity)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print (f (Foo (Just 1) (Just 2) (Just (3 :| []))))
```

This prints:

```
Just (Foo {x = Identity 1, y = Identity 2, others = Identity (3 :| [])})
```